# How many sessions are with specific event triggered multiple times?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-events

I have an event action: `event_a` that users can trigger by interacting with the page.

How can I find out how many sessions were in which users triggered the `event_a` more than once?

I tried setting up a custom segment:

- Sessions include:

  - Event Action: contains `event_a`
  - Total Events > 1

But I get all sessions that event was triggered.

I also tried going to the Top Events report, and try to filter on the same conditions as above, getting the same result.

Comment: As you probably heard, GA is not a tool for identifying users and theirs behaviour. But you can do it that way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060707/linking-google-analytics-event-logs-to-unique-session-id

Answer (score 1):

The Top Events reports has the number you are looking for.   It is called "Unique Events".

[image]

From the context sensitive help:

- **Total Events** - Total Events is the number of times events occurred.
- **Unique Events** - The number of times during a date range that a session contained the specific dimension or combination of dimensions.

So the "total" is the number of times that event occurred and the "unique" is the number of sessions for which it occurred.  The difference between the two is the number of events that were triggered in the same session.

Comment: This only tells me how many sessions in which the event occured. I can calculate an average of events per session but it doesn't tell me how many sessions with more than 1 event occured. It can be one session with 247 (528 - 281) events and 281 sessions with 1 event each or any other combination.

Comment: When I need to know that info, I have generally created a different event the second time it happens for that user.  For example, an event when the user plays a video, but then when the user pauses and presses play again, I'll send an "unpause" event rather than a second "play" event.

Comment: I will consider this as a technique in the future, but it's rarely that I know beforehand how I would use the data collected by Analytics. It's just not effective enough to worth the effort. Analytics has that data. Why does it hide it from the users?